# Node/express, optional parameters switch route between get and post

Tags: node.js, express

I have 2 routes set up for my express server that look very close to each other. They are basically the same url, except one is post and one is get, and the get has an extra route param (which is optional). Right now these seem to work ok, however if I do not add the optional param to the get call, it thinks I'm trying to hit the post. I would like to be able to hit the get call without the passing the second optional param as well. Let me show you what I have so far:

```
router.param('itemID', (req, res, next, itemID) => {
    verbose("itemID=", itemID);
    next();
});

router.param('navigationType', (req, res, next, navigationType) => {
    if (!navigationType) {
        next();
    }
    verbose("navigationType=", navigationType);
    next();
}); 

router.route('/:itemID/navigations')
    .post(controllers.addActivity)
    .all(routes.send405.bind(null, ['POST']));

router.route('/:itemID/navigations/:navigationType')
    .get(controllers.listActivities)
    .all(routes.send405.bind(null, ['GET']));
```

The routed.send405 method looks like this :

```
function send405(methods, req, res) {
    res.set('Allow', methods.join(','));
    res.status(405).json({
        message: `Method '${req.method}' Not Allowed.`
    });
}
```

So right now the issue is if I do a get on `/blah123/navigations` and don't add the `/:navigationType` variable, it thinks I am trying to hit the post method. I am very new to working with this and would appreciate any help or insight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a route, say `GET /admins/:id`, it will match any requests to `GET /admins/1` or `GET /admins/john`. But when you do just `GET /admins`, it wouldn't be able to find because you haven't declared GET route matching that pattern.

To work with this, you have to specify `navigationType` is an optional parameter and also place the GET request first followed by the POST, like this.

```
router.route('/:itemID/navigations/:navigationType?')
    .get(controllers.listActivities)
    .all(routes.send405.bind(null, ['GET'])); 

router.route('/:itemID/navigations')
    .post(controllers.addActivity)
    .all(routes.send405.bind(null, ['POST']));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however this does not seem to solve the problem.